# Installing openssh-server on RPi 2 (Ubuntu Mate)

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, openssh, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to install openssh-server on RPi 2 with fresh Ubuntu Mate using etc/rc.local. So i tried to use this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

apt-get update && apt-get -y install openssh-server

exit 0
```

but nothing installed or changed on RPi. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: run 'sudo service ssh status'